# Is it possible to improve the performance of this subquery?

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, aggregation

For my application I have a topic table and a vote table. The vote options are -1, 0, and 1. I'm trying to find the amount of times each topic was voted -1 and 1.

So to find out, I am doing many subqueries, each of which uses the algorithm of `find total number of -1 or 1 votes and then divide by the total number of votes`.

Unfortunately, what I came up with is very slow. In part because I am calculating the count twice, but I'm not sure if it's possible to reference it from the outer query.

Can the performance of this be improved?

```
SELECT title,
  (SELECT COUNT(vote)::float8 FROM vote WHERE topic_id = v1.topic_id AND vote_choice = -1) 
/ (SELECT COUNT(vote)::float8 FROM vote WHERE topic_id = v1.topic_id) as lp,
  (SELECT COUNT(vote)::float8 FROM vote WHERE topic_id = v1.topic_id AND vote_choice = 1) 
/ (SELECT COUNT(vote)::float8 FROM vote WHERE topic_id = v1.topic_id) as rp
FROM topic
JOIN vote v1 ON topic.id = v1.topic_id 
GROUP BY v1.topic_id, topic.title;
```

Comment: Is it a requirement that all the data is in 1 row? you could alter it to `SELECT vote_choice, COUNT(vote_choice)` and in the group by add `vote_choice`. but then you'd have 1 row for each vote_choice with the count.

Comment: I'm not really following you. There can be many votes for a single topic, so I have to group by the topic and not the vote choice.

Comment: iam tempted to say rewrite the corelated subqueries to use joins instead.. but without table structures and a explain we know to little to give valid advice..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use `FILTER` instead of correlated subqueries:

```
SELECT 
    title,
    1.0 * COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE vote_choice = -1) / COUNT(*) as lp,
    1.0 * COUNT(*) FILTER(WHERE vote_choice = 1)  / COUNT(*) as rp
FROM topic
JOIN vote v1 ON topic.id = v1.topic_id 
GROUP BY v1.topic_id, topic.title;
```

Comment: I think `COUNT(vote)` should be `COUNT(v1)` (since you're not selecting from subquery anymore but from `vote` which is aliased to `v1`), but works great (I re-created his structure locally)

Comment: @Mark Yes, I agree. `*` is the safest option here.

Comment: Thank you. This improved the performance 10x. I had never heard of the `FILTER` keyword before. I'll do some reading on it.

Comment: @RyanPeschel It is really great to hear it :)

Answer (score 2):

Given your description this can be done using using conditional aggregation:

```
select title, 
       count(vote) as total_count,
       count(vote)::numeric filter (where vote_choice = -1) / count(vote)::numeric as lp,
       count(vote)::numeric filter (where vote_choice = 1) / count(vote) as rp
from topic t
  join vote v on t.id = v.topic_id
group by title;
```

Comment: Great minds think alike. Unfortunately I can only accept one answer.